# Não seria o caso de usar tags especificando se escreveu em PT-BR ou PT-PT?

Tags: debate, tags

Estou encontrando dificuldade com algumas perguntas.

Não sei se a pessoa escreveu rápido demais e escreveu errado ou se escreveu em PT-PT e eu não entendi direito.

Não seria o caso de fazer tags dizendo se a postagem foi feita em `PT-PT` ou `PT-BR` ou ainda encorajar as pessoas a fazerem alguma indicação sobre qual língua utiliza?

Achei interessante o caso na pergunta "[Como fazer um textBox que atualiza sempre que se muda o conteúdo?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3020/como-fazer-um-textbox-que-atualiza-sempre-que-se-muda-o-conteudo)" onde o usuário utilizou a palavra `despoletasse` e depois por solicitação em um comentário colocou como é no Brasil.

Comment: [pt-br] - Opa, acho justo! lol

Comment: Esse verbo "despoletar" apareceu numa pergunta durante o beta privado. Quando vi alguém removendo numa edição da pergunta que você mencionou, desfiz a edição e acrescentei a nota com a "tradução" para pt_BR. Sempre bom aprender palavras novas, né?

Comment: @bfavaretto Sim, citei porque achei muito legal a atitude inclusive colocando qual o significado no `PT-BR`.

Answer (score 24):

**Não**. As tags devem ser usadas para ajudar identificar sobre o que o problema é.

Temos aqui uma grande oportunidade de aprendermos um pouco mais. Eu estou adorando ver essas **palavras novas da nossa língua**.

Quando tiver dúvidas, **comente** para entender, para aprender algo novo. Vá ao chat perguntar o que é a palavra. Pesquise o que é.

Durante o beta privado nos demos muito bem com essa diversidade.

Comment: Além disso tudo, se a ideia é um site pra **toda** a comunidade, não faria sentido segregar o conteúdo

Comment: Ok, tags não foi uma boa. Mas talvez uma indicação para quem ler saber como está escrito. Vi uma pergunta aqui no meta que estavam sugerindo edições para uma língua em perguntas escritas em outra língua.

Comment: Até agora todo mundo aqui nessa questão é brasileiro, vamos ver a opinião de um lusitano (é assim que fala, né?).

Comment: @VitorCanova Ou "tuga" para os íntimos :)

Comment: +1 pelo segundo parágrafo. Matando dois coelhos com uma comunidade só (imaginar a cena é meio engraçado)

Comment: Como alguém com o português como segundo idioma, concordo plenamente com bigown! Acabo aprendendo várias coisas novas!

Answer (score 18):

Acho que devemos seguir o exemplo do Stack Overflow original.

Lá existem pessoas que escrevem nas seguintes formas de inglês:

- britânico;
- australiano (semelhante com o anterior, mas ainda bastante distinto);
- americano "tradicional";
- americano "sulista";
- asiático (a.k.a. "Engrish");
- latino (a.k.a. "Spanglish");
- fora vários outros sotaques, que inevitavelmente são levados a texto também.

E todos se entendem muito bem. Por que nós, que utilizamos principalmente apenas duas formas, não podemos nos entender? Seria custoso entender que `ecrã` e `tela` são a mesma coisa? É difícil aceitar que `arquivo` é sinônimo de `ficheiro`?

Se levarmos a ideia de se etiquetar perguntas com o dialeto utilizado, abrimos precedente para a filtragem de questões por dialeto, o que apenas dividiria o SOePT em subcomunidades.

Com relação ao idioma, prefiro da forma como está; A exposição à prosa dos companheiros de além-mar me enriquece o vocabulário.

Comment: +1. Sem falar no Inglês brasileiro, Inglês chinês e etc. Muito bem colocado.

Comment: No Stack Overflow original o que mais tem é pergunta em inglês mal-escrita e difícil de entender, principalmente entre usuários novatos de outros países que sabem pouco inglês. É sempre um exercício de interpretação, mas no final todos se entendem. Mas também há mal-entendidos, principalmente quando envolvem código. Para os americanos `()` são parentheses, `[]` são brackets e `{}` são curly braces. Já os ingleses chamam tudo de *brackets* (*round*, *square* and *curly*). É bem fácil misturar tudo :D

Answer (score 8):

Em teoria o português é um idioma unificado, portanto não há necessidade de diferenciação por país ou região.

Isso abriria precedente pra, por exemplo, abrir tags para o Norte, Nordeste, Sudeste, Centro-Oeste e Sul do Brasil, Portugal, Angola, Moçambique e Macau.